# While I compile the program in borland c++ I get "Unable to open include file 'owl/owlpch.h'" error

Tags: c++, borland-c++

As I am compiling my program I am not able to include the header files as shown by the compiler, I've changed the environment variables  and configured the bcc32.cfg and Ilink32.cfg file but still It didn't helped.

[image: snapshot of the errors]

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you chose the Borland C++ compiler?

Comment: In my project everybody uses borland, to maintain the uniformity I am bound to use borland :(

Comment: I see. If the reason your groups sticks to Borland C++ is [Object Windows Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Windows_Library), then you may very well use GCC or VC++ and use the [OWLNext](http://sourceforge.net/projects/owlnext/) library (a more advanced version of OWL).

Answer (score 2):

which version of Borland C++ are you using?

If it is Borland C++ 5.01/5.02, then it is including the OWL headers and libraries - check if they are installed.

If, on the other hand, you are trying to use the free compiler, Borland C++ 5.5, or even C++Builder, then it does not include OWL headers and libraries. Your best bet is to head over to [OWLNext](http://sourceforge.net/projects/owlnext/) (the open-source upgrade for OWL) and get a version of the library that is compatible with your compiler.

Comment: Yes, I am using Borland C++ 5.02, seems OWL header and libraries are already installed.

Comment: if you are using BC5.02 IDE, then check from the menu Options->Project->Directories if the Include and Library directories are set up correctly.